# Set plot labels in overlayed figure (boxplot + barplot)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to make an overlayed figure using a boxplot + barplot. I managed to overlap the two plots but I can't set the labels of the barplot.

Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4)+3,
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
boxplot = df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])  

ax = plt.gca()
b = ax.bar(0,5)
```

Code output:
[image]

How can I add a label to the boxplot? (e.g. 'Col0') I've tried the functions `set_label()`, `bar_label()` and `set_xticklabels()` but I didn't manage to solve the issue.

Related threads:
[Overlay box plots on bars matplotlib/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837142/overlay-box-plots-on-bars-matplotlib-python)

[How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/how-to-add-value-labels-on-a-bar-chart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use plt.xticks() which adds the label.

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# --------------------------- #
 
# Creating dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': [1, 2, 3],
    'Col2': [3, 4, 5],
    'Col3': [2, 1, 2]
})

# Define the axes of the plot
ax = plt.subplot()

# Add the boxplot
boxplot = df.boxplot()

# Add the barchart
ax.bar(0, 5)

# Store all the x-ticks label in this tuple
objects = ('Col0', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))  # The position of the labels

# Add the ticks to the plot
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

So this code `ax.bar_label(b, 'Col0')` , and adds a label at the top but ends up throwing an error.
A kind-of hacky solution is to manually add a text for "Col0" at the required location:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4)+3,
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
boxplot = df.boxplot(column=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])  

ax = plt.gca()
b = ax.bar(0,5)
ax.text(0,-0.4,'Col0', ha="center", va="bottom")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]